# Angular JS - ng-required attribute not working

Tags: angularjs

I have written the following code to display a span below a text box when the user has not entered the full name. But the below code is not working. Could any body help to understand this? Thanks

```
<div class="form-group">
         <label for="fullName" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Name </label>
         <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" 
                           class="form-control"
                 ng-model="editableEmployee.fullName" ng-required="true" />
              <span ng-show="editableEmployee.fullName.$error.required">
                        Full name is required </span>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell the meaning of "not working"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a form element like this

```
<form name="myForm">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fullName" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Name </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" class="form-control" ng-model="editableEmployee.fullName" ng-required="true" />
          <span ng-show="myForm.fullName.$error.required">Full name is required </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @SankarKrishnamoorthy if your problem got solved, pls approve my answer

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that I am using ng-model value for ng-show. The ng-show variable should be referred to Formname.FieldName Where as the ng-model should be referred to ScopeObjectName.Variablename

[Picture showing that the ng-model and ng-show are using the same name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc1rc.gif)